# how to check if div has id or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="cardSlots">
<div class="ui-droppable" tabindex="-1" id="card1">one</div>
<div class="ui-droppable" tabindex="-1" id="card2">two</div>
<div class="ui-droppable" tabindex="-1">three</div>
<div class="ui-droppable" tabindex="-1">four</div>
</div>

<script>
     $(".ui-droppable").each(function () {     
       if($(this).attr("id").length>0)
       {
       alert('here');
       }
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to loop through class but issue is i have card1 and card2 ids duplicate in that page. but above code seems to work but showing below error.

```
Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I am trying to get ids from the loop which are there.

Comment: I hope this doesn't sound rude, but I think you should learn more about JavaScript, before you jump into jQuery

Comment: jQuery is a weird paradox.  It is set up to make programming JavaScript easy, which makes it great for beginners; however, it is still JS and so a user should first be familiar with at least native JavaScript object interactions (properties/method calls)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use **attribute selector** `selector[attribute]` to get only the elements that have an ID

```
$('.myClass[id]')   // Get .myClass elements that have ID attribute
```

In your case:

```
$('.ui-droppable[id]').each(function(){
   alert( this.id );
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/eNcDP/1/)

Comment: This is also a good answer, which gets at what the question was looking for, but not necessarily asking

Answer (score 12):

`if(this.id)` is all you need.

---

**Why will this work?**

If the element has an ID, the value will a non-empty string, which always evaluates to `true`.
If it does not have an ID, the value is an empty string which evaluates to `false`.

---

> I am trying to get ids from the loop which are there.

To get a list of IDs, you can use `.map` like so:

```
var ids = $(".ui-droppable").map(function() {     
    return this.id ? this.id : null;
}).get();
```

or use the selector [Roko suggests in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11137426/218196).

Comment: the descriptive alternative: `if(this.id && this.id.length > $somenum)`

Answer (score 3):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/QRv6d/13/

APi link: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Please try this, this should help

**code**

```
   $(".ui-droppable").each(function () { 

       if($(this).prop("id").length > 0)
       {
       alert('here');
       }
    });​
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is no `id` attribute `attr` method will return `undefined`. Just write:

```
if($(this).attr("id"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeof $(this).attr("id") != 'undefined')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var $this = $(this);
if (typeof $this.attr("id") != "undefined" && $this.attr("id").length > 0) {
    ...
}
```

If you're going to use `$(this)` more than once, it's advised to find it once, and put the resulting jQuery object in a local variable.