# jQuery if Element has an ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I select elements that have any ID? For example:

```
if ($(".parent a").hasId()) {
    /* then do something here */
}
```

I, by no means, am a master at jQuery.

Comment: Use `.is('[id]');` to check if a specific element has an `id` attribute at all. Or if you need to filter a collection of elements, use `.filter('[id]')` and then compare the `.length` property

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you actually planning to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery get only all html elements with ids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163888/jquery-get-only-all-html-elements-with-ids)

Comment: jQuery documentation: [Has Attribute Selector \[name\]](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).

Comment: Do you want to "select elements" to do something with/to them, or test if any such elements exist?

Comment: I just want to do be able to fire off a script if there are elements within the parent class that have the id attribute in the element.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, suggestions, and improvements! :)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Like this:

```
var $aWithId = $('.parent a[id]');
```

Following OP's comment, test it like this:

```
if($aWithId.length) //or without using variable: if ($('.parent a[id]').length)
```

Will return all anchor tags inside elements with class parent which have an attribute ID specified

Comment: You mean `if ($('.parent a[id]').length)` ?

Answer (score 51):

You can use jQuery's .is() function.

> if ( $(".parent a").is("#idSelector") ) {
>
> ```
> //Do stuff
> ```
>
> }

It will return true if the parent anchor has *#idSelector* id.

Comment: No. That will tell you if an element has a *specific* id. The question is asking if it has any id. See the answer from two years ago that was accepted.

Comment: This is a great answer however if you want to check if the element has a specific id! +1

Answer (score 7):

You can do

```
document.getElementById(id) or 
$(id).length > 0
```

Comment: No, the OP is trying to determine which elements have an id attribute defined with any value, not select by a specific, known id.

Answer (score 6):

You can using the following code:

```
   if($(".parent a").attr('id')){

      //do something
   }


   $(".parent a").each(function(i,e){
       if($(e).attr('id')){
          //do something and check
          //if you want to break the each
          //return false;
       }
   });
```

The same question is you can find here: [how to check if div has id or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137317/how-to-check-if-div-has-id-or-not)

Comment: But the question says "elements" (plural), and `.attr()` will only get the id from the first element matching that selector.

Answer (score 5):

Number of `.parent a` elements that have an `id` attribute:

```
$('.parent a[id]').length
```

Comment: But the question says "elements" (plural), and `.attr()` will only get the id from the first element matching that selector.

Comment: You are right so it's more `$('.parent a[id]').length`. Answer updated

Answer (score 5):

**Simple way:**

Fox example this is your html,

```
<div class='classname' id='your_id_name'>
</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
if($('.classname').prop('id')=='your_id_name')
{
    //works your_id_name exist (true part)
}
else
{ 
    //works your_id_name not exist (false part)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I seemed to have been able to solve it with:

```
if( $('your-selector-here').attr('id') === undefined){
    console.log( 'has no ID' )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pure js approach:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');
alert(elem[0].hasAttribute('id'));
```

[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3bh50ghv/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
if ($(".parent a[Id]").length > 0) {

    /* then do something here */

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This answer was already contributed multiple times. Please check other answers first.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
$(".parent a[id]");
```

Comment: roasted already provided the exact same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17277848/218196.

Answer (score 0):

You can use each() function to evalute all a tags and bind click to that specific element you clicked on. Then throw some logic with an if statement.

See [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jaqoLnts/1/).

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var el= $(this).attr('id');
        if (el === 'notme') {
            // do nothing or something else
        } else {
            $('p').toggle();
        }
    });
});
```