# js - check if same class elements have id

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I have 2 input tags:

```
<input type="text" class="mainText" id="input">
<input type="text" class="mainText">
```

I need to set id to the input tag that don't have id, may be with jQuery like:

```
if(input tag has no id){
    $(".mainText").attr("id", "someInput");
}
```

How could I find this non id input?

Comment: duplicate of question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277821/jquery-if-element-has-an-id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the magic of jQuery selectors:

```
$('.mainText:not([id])').prop('id', 'someInput');
```

It will select all elements with `.mainText` class that does `:not` have attribute `[id]`.

Comment: Shouldnt it be `.mainText:not([id])`?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon True! `has` will work differently. I'm a bit tired already.

Answer (score 0):

`.has(your ID)` will return false if no ID been found.

see document here: http://api.jquery.com/has/