# Why does element.id on element without id not return undefined or null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137317/how-to-check-if-div-has-id-or-not) and dealing with a similar situation, I wonder whether anyone can explain the *rationale* behind the decision to have element.id return an empty string when the id attribute is not present.

If the spec was to return `null` or `undefined` I could simply write

```
var allIds = $('#my-frm input').map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```

Instead I have to either add a qualifier to the selector, as in

```
var allIds = $('#my-frm input[id]').map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```

or use the other solution proposed to the above-mentioned question (which has to get the id twice in case it is present)

```
var allIds = $('#my-frm input').map(function() { return (this.id) ? this.id : null; }).get();
```

or I can use the jquery attribute getter, which seems unnecessary to wrap each element into a jquery object first, but I'm mentioning it for completeness and to show that jquery went the other direction with the .attr() method.

```
var allIds = $('#my-frm input').map(function() { return $(this).attr('id'); }).get();
```

I'm curious if there is a practical reason behind the javascript element.id behavior.

## Update:

I finally located the relevant spec, which *defines* the current behavior (it doesn't explain *why* it was defined this way)

https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-dom-20151119/#element

```
interface Element : Node {
  readonly attribute DOMString? namespaceURI;
  readonly attribute DOMString? prefix;
  readonly attribute DOMString localName;
  readonly attribute DOMString tagName;

           attribute DOMString id;
           attribute DOMString className;
...
```

Either when an element is created that has an `id` attribute whose value is not the empty string or when an element's `id` attribute is set to a value other than the empty string, set the element's ID to the new value.

When an element's `id` attribute is removed or set to the empty string, unset the element's ID.

---

Some IDL attributes are defined to reflect a particular content attribute of a given name. This means that on getting, these steps must be run:

1. Get an attribute for the context object using content attribute's name and let value be the result.
2. **If value is null, return the empty string.**
3. Return value.

On setting, set an attribute for the context object using the name of the attribute and the given value.

The `id` attribute must reflect the "`id`" content attribute.

Comment: does `return this.id || null;` return null when you want it to?

Comment: Can't you use `filter` first? Empty string is falsy... Why do you want nulls?

Comment: I think that the spec says that all elements must have an "id" property, but if it's a "real" id it has to be at least one character long; otherwise it's a degenerate id and it's the empty string.

Comment: `I'm curious if there is a practical reason` - history? changing it would break the world wide web too much? why does it matter?

Comment: Sorry, but my question is not to help me code my situation. I appreciate the suggestions, but I'm really after understanding the RATIONALE behind the javascript spec for element.id. Is there a better forum to ask this type of question?

Comment: +1 for @JaromandaX. You made me smile. Don't worry, I'm not trying to change it and risk breaking the whole www.

Comment: @RudigerW. Note that this has nothing at all to do with JavaScript the programming language - this is a W3C thing involving standardized web APIs. Those are not language specific *in principle*.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks for pointing that out. I could rephrase my question. Maybe there's also another SO tag that would be more appropriate.

Comment: I know you aren't trying to break the WWW ... but there are quirks that remain in javascript simply because fixing them would probably break so many websites

Answer (score 3):

> I'm curious if there is a practical reason behind the javascript
>   element.id behavior.

See [`Element.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)

> The `Element.id` property represents the element's identifier,
>   reflecting the [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) global attribute.

---

> If the spec was to return `null` or `undefined`

[3.2.5.1 The id attribute](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

> Identifiers are opaque strings. Particular meanings should not be
>   derived from the value of the id attribute.
>
> **Note** There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit,
>   start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.
>
> **Note** An element's unique identifier can be used for a variety of purposes, most notably as a way to link to specific parts of a
>   document using fragment identifiers, as a way to target an element
>   when scripting, and as a way to style a specific element from CSS.

---

> It's funny how the result is kind of opposite of the intent. Because I
>   want to avoid calling a separate method to check for the existence of
>   `id`

To substituting `$.map()` for `.map()` , `Array.prototype.filter()` with parameter `Boolean` for `.get()` to return `id` that is not empty string

```
var allIds = $.map($("input"), function(el) {
               return el.id
             }).filter(Boolean);
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gqvfuzqr/

Comment: thanks for the reference! It's funny how the result is kind of opposite of the intent. Because I want to avoid calling a separate method to check for the existence of `id` I end up giving the `empty string` value special meaning.

Comment: Is requirement to a) check for existence of `id` ; b) reduce method calls; c) return `id` of element where it is not an empty string ? Not certain if Question is restricted to why `id` returns empty string if not set, or how to return `id` where exists at element or how to reduce method calls ?

Comment: So, the section of the spec you referenced doesn't actually say what the value is when the attribute is not present. Otherwise it would contradict itself. `The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character.` Well, all the elements that *don't* have id attributes now return the empty string which is 1) not unique 2) not at least one character long.

Comment: _"Identifiers are opaque strings."_ Not certain what expected result of Question is ? What is requirement ?

Comment: @RudigerW. I think that the root issue may be that *all* elements have an "id" property, and `null` really isn't a W3C DOM standards concept.

Comment: The point of the questions was to see if it was a random decision or had a practical reason why identifiers were specified to be strings and not allowing null.

Comment: The `requirement` for my code is to be 1) easy to read/understand 2) not stupidly inefficient. In this case I'm dealing with a handful of elements, so efficiency is not a concern, i.e. legibility of the code is top priority.

Comment: @RudigerW. _"it doesn't explain why it was defined this way"_ `html` is, in essense, composed as a string. How would `null` or `undefined` be represented as a string other than an empty string ? Does using `$.map()` and `.filter(Boolean)` make `js` simpler to read / understand what is occurring ?

Comment: I have to disagree with @Pointy that `null` is not a W3C DOM standards concept. Follow the link to the DOM element spec I put in the update of my question and you will find `null` mentioned 185 times on that page.

Comment: guest271314: HTML is composed as a string but HTML does not mandate the id property of element. The DOM does and the DOM has the concept of `null` and `undefined`. And what better way to represent `null` or `undefined` than the *absence* of the attribute altogether?

Comment: @RudigerW. Yes, how would `null` or `undefined` be represented as a string when composing `html` ? `<div id="null"></div>` ? or `<div id="undefined"></div>` ? The `id` would no longer  be an empty string. Would still require some form of processing to determine that `id="null"` or `id="undefined"` should return `undefined` or `null` . Simplest appears to be empty string `""` which returns `false` or "falsey" at both `if` condition and `Boolean("")`. Could possibly create a custom element using `.registerElement` where `prototype` of element that did not have `id` set could return `undefined`

Comment: @RudigerW. the simple fact is that if you interrogate the "id" property of a DOM  element that does not have an explicit "id" attribute, the value returned is the empty string (`""`).

Comment: @RudigerW. wait - *you already located the spec.* What is it that you're asking? Are you asking why the spec is the way it is?